# Calculating Phase Response for 2 microphones given the input

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, phase, sound

I want to measure and compare the phase response of two identical microphones. To do this, I have a pressure chamber, which allows to apply the same pressure to both microphones.

I apply a sweeped sine wave to the chamber to measure the freq. range of interest.
As Data I have the applied pressure and the measured pressure of the two microphones.

Right know I do the following:

```
fftChamber = fft(chamber_sig)
fftMic1 = fft(mic1_sig)
fftMic2 = fft(mic2_sig)
G1 = fftMic1./fftChamber
G2 = fftMic2./fftChamber
phaseResponse1 = angle(G1)
phaseResponse2 = angle(G2)
```

This method gives me the most reasonable result, but I'm not sure why dividing should be right or appropriate, as this is not really a transfer-function?

Comment: how is this not a transfer function?

Comment: well it somehow is.

Comment: it pretty much is the very definition of a transfer function